# MongoDB group with project

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to select maximum value of a field along with the time it occured.

```
db.temperaterdata.aggregate([     
        {  
            $match: { 
                        $and: [  
                             { "organization_id": 37 },  
                             { 
                                "resulttime":{ 
                                              $gte:'2020-05-01 00:00',                                           
                                              $lte:'2020-05-29 23:59'   
                                            }  
                             } 
                            ]  
                    }  
        },
        { 
           "$group": {          
                        "_id": "$userid", 
                        maxTemperature: { $max: "$temperature"},         
                        minTemperature: { $min: "$temperature"}     
                    }
        },
        {
           "$project": {
                        "resulttime":1, 
                        maxTemperature:1,
                        minTemperature:1
                    }

        }        
]);
```

However, the time for which the maximum/minimum temperature has occurred it's not showing up. The result coming is like this:

```
{ "_id" : 233, "maxTemperature" : 100.67, "minTemperature" : 98.56 }
{ "_id" : 256, "maxTemperature" : 100.67, "minTemperature" : 98.56 }
{ "_id" : 263, "maxTemperature" : 100.67, "minTemperature" : 98.56 }
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: can you provide an example of `temperaterdata`

Comment: { "_id" : ObjectId("5eb9495ae1d57b7b90c0fb15"), "userid" : 158, "temperature" : "98.56", "resulttime" : "2020-05-11 18:17:21", "inserttime" : "5/11/2020 18:17:22", "organization_id" : 1 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to order by `userId + temperature` and take max / min documents with [$first](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) / [$last](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/) operators.

Try the query below:

```
db.temperaterdata.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "organization_id": 37,
      "resulttime": {
        "$gte": "2020-05-01 00:00",
        "$lte": "2020-05-29 23:59"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "userid": 1,
      "temperature": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$userid",
      "maxTemperature": {
        "$last": "$$ROOT"
      },
      "minTemperature": {
        "$first": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "maxresulttime": "$maxTemperature.resulttime",
      "minresulttime": "$minTemperature.resulttime",
      "maxTemperature": "$maxTemperature.temperature",
      "minTemperature": "$minTemperature.temperature"
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/iCY9o86f-G_)